# Python Doing something for every entry in list?

Tags: python, list, trello

So I've been interacting with the trello API through python.
When I get my cards it returns (Among others) this list (Converted it to JSON for prettiness)

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "id": "censored",
      "checkItemStates": null,
      "closed": false,
      "dateLastActivity": "2017-03-13T20:31:15.161Z",
      "desc": "",
      "descData": null,
      "idBoard": "censored",
      "idList": "censored",
      "idMembersVoted": [

  ],
  "idShort": 1,
  "idAttachmentCover": null,
  "manualCoverAttachment": false,
  "idLabels": [

  ],
  "name": "testcard1",
  "pos": 65535,
  "shortLink": "censored",
  "badges": {
    "votes": 0,
    "viewingMemberVoted": false,
    "subscribed": false,
    "fogbugz": "",
    "checkItems": 0,
    "checkItemsChecked": 0,
    "comments": 0,
    "attachments": 0,
    "description": false,
    "due": null,
    "dueComplete": false
  },
  "dueComplete": false,
  "due": null,
  "email": "censored",
  "idChecklists": [

  ],
  "idMembers": [

  ],
  "labels": [

  ],
  "shortUrl": "censored",
  "subscribed": false,
  "url": "censored",
  "attachments": [

  ],
  "pluginData": [

  ]
}
  ]
}
```

Ive tried

```
for card in x.cards:
print "hi"
```

But it throws me this Error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cards'
```

My Ultimate goal is to get every "name" attribute and print it in an txt file (I know how to write stuff to .txt files tho)

In the final result, there's gonna be more thn 1 card ofc.

Comment: Try printing `x` itself first. It isn't the `json` you are expecting. Also, you would likely need to use `x['cards']` instead of `x.cards`.

Comment: That doesn't help me at all, x["cards"] does nothing even when you convert it to json or not.

Comment: Like I mentioned, check your `x` first. Print it out. See it's contents and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the py-trello API to retrieve data from your boards. It is pretty easy get the attributes from your cards. See sample below:

```
from trello import TrelloClient

def main():
    client = TrelloClient(
        api_key=TRELLO_API_KEY,
        api_secret=TRELLO_API_SECRET,
        token=TRELLO_OAUTH,
        token_secret=TRELLO_OAUTH_SECRET
    )

    boards = client.list_boards()

    for b in boards:
        print("\n# {}\n\n".format(b.name))
        print_board(b)

def print_board(board):
    lists = board.list_lists()
    for l in lists:
        print("\n## {}\n".format(l.name))
        print_list(l)

def print_list(lst):
    cards = lst.list_cards()
    for c in cards:
    print("* {}".format(c.name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For more info see https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello and https://github.com/sarumont/py-trello/issues/181 
Example credits for https://github.com/berezovskyi